# Add the Play Games Services SDK to your production APK to use the APIs'

Tags: google-play-games

'Add the Play Games Services SDK to your production APK to use the APIs' Hi I published a game on Play Store ' Jetpack Man' using Unreal Engine however I want to add leaderboards and got stuck on this step. I have no idea how do this using Android Studio and apply it to my game?

Comment: What steps have you followed to add the SDK to your project? Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 2):

I manged to publish my game without having this step checked.

Comment: is this meant as a comment?